# How to get so the rows in a table doesn't get filled with unneeded spaces to fill out everything

Tags: sql-server, sql-types

I have a table which fills out the rows I have put in there with spaces if the thing I put in there isn't long enough.

For example:
I have a string called

```
'ABC'
```

but the column is a `nchar(10)`
so the value which is put in there becomes

```
'ABC       '
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

I am working in MSSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nchar` is a fixed width datatype and will always be padded out with spaces up to the defined column limit. You would need `nvarchar(10)` to avoid this.

You should generally only use `nchar` in preference to `nvarchar` when the values in the column all have the same or very similar lengths.

Answer (score 1):

`nchar(10)` is a fixed length string. 
`nvarchar(10)` is not.

You could change the column definition to `nvarchar(10)`